# How to make a table that could add many same number of different item?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I wanted to create a table to store coupons of users.

For example, there is 3 coupon which is A, B and C etc. A user can have 10 coupon A, 20 coupon B and 5 coupon C etc.

How should I create a table to store these? There are many users in the system. How should I create a table which able to store all these information?

If I add another table just for the user and the coupon I still need to add a table which can count the number of the coupon. I have 8 type of coupon. Can I just use a single table and store each coupon for each column and row for the number of coupon?

Comment: it all depends on your requirements, let's say you need to how many coupons a user has, how many used, how many remaining? Think several scenarios you gonna face. Then we can design a table. Otherwise, you gonna end up in changing the schema later which will be difficult.

Comment: owhhh ok now I realize that I forgot the coupon count should be in the third table thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it correctly with a single table, more exactly your database will be redundant and seriously vulnerable against inconsistencies.

You should read about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

A normalized solution would be this:

1. Table `users`, columns:

   1. user_id (integer, also primary key)
   2. ...any other user data, name etc...
2. Table `coupons`, columns:

   1. coupon_id (integer, also primary key)
   2. ...any other coupon data, name, value, etc...
3. Table `user_coupon` (**it is the important**), it is a so named bridge table, columns:

   1. user_id (foreign key to `users(user_id)`)
   2. coupon_id (foreign key to `coupons(coupon_id)`)
   3. count (integer, shows how many coupons with id `coupon_id` has the user `user_id`)

The important thing is that the primary key on table `user_coupon` must be `user_id` and `coupon_id`!

Comment: Comment discussion about exchanging personal contact information removed. Profiles may be used for this, but please bear in mind this is not how the SE model is intended to operate. Please see [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/431) on meta, and the [linked FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users).